# How to debug Visual Studio Code extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

What are the best ways to troubleshoot and debug Visual Studio Code?

I have encountered conflicts in some snippet/suggestion extensions while editing in Visual Studio Code and want to try to find the root cause.

<sup>P.S. I would appreciate any experience in resolving conflicts between extensions. Feel free to chime in if you have encountered this issue before (built-in suggestions completely overwriting extension suggestions after a couple of seconds)</sup>

Comment: I have images, but lack of reputation prevents me from creating embedded images for clearer questions.

Comment: Forked smaller question component for clarity from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51097273/vs-code-ide-extensions-how-to-debug-snippets-conflicting-extensions-or-sugges?noredirect=1#comment89282896_51097273%3E after raising issues about deprecated built-in suggestions overriding snippet extensions on the GitHub repo.

Comment: Also worth noting you can see your console output by `Help > Toggle Developer Tools`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Taken from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/developing-extensions:

> ### Running and debugging your extension
>
> You can easily run your extension under the debugger by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>.
>   This opens a new VS Code window with your extension loaded. Output
>   from your extension shows up in the `Debug Console`. You can set break
>   points, step through your code, and inspect variables either in the
>   `Debug` view or the `Debug Console`.

To debug installed Visual Studio Code extensions, first **navigate to the installed extension's project folder.**

> %USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extension\${PublisherName}.${ExtensionName}-${VersionNumber}\

This folder is contained in your user profile or root folder. It may also be called `.vscode-insiders` depending on the version of Visual Studio Code you have installed.

This project folder should already have the debugger set up and **you can just press <kbd>F5</kbd>** in a project source file to open the `[Extension Development Host]` as originally assumed.

For more information you can check the `<projectroot>/.vscode/launch.json` to find the launch configurations detailing the use of the `[Extension Development Host]` if you need to fine-tune these settings.

Example taken from auto-generated extension debugger settings `launch.json`:

```js
// A launch configuration that compiles the extension and then opens it inside a new window

{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "configurations": [{
    "name": "Launch Extension",
    "type": "extensionHost",
    "request": "launch",
    "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
    "args": ["--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceRoot}"]
  }]
}
```

From there it's just a simple(~) matter of adding breakpoints and/or console logs to work out the cause of extension-related issues.

[image: Image of extension debugger after launching with <kbd>F5</kbd>] *~ Edit: I have enough rep to embed images now*

For more information on general development of Visual Studio Code extensions see the official docs here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/developing-extensions#_creating-your-own-extension

Comment: I don't understand this. If I push F5 it runs my project, not a specific extension. How would I run an extension using this?

Comment: I suppose it will start at this entrypoint `"main": "./out/extension.js"` from `package.json` and begin debugging the extension. So make sure to build that file (depending on your configuration).

Answer (score 13):

To view the errors for someone else's extension you installed normally:

- In the menu, select `View` > `Output`
- Select the extension in a small dropdown at the top right of the output window

[image]

Comment: In the same dropdown, `Log (Extension Host)` can also be useful for diagnosing problems with extensions.